# How does xgboost generate the base learner set

Tags: python, xgboost

guys, I am new to xgboost and not native English speaker, so I hope you will not get mad if I have made some stupid mistakes.
I just wander about how does xgboost(set the boost model as gbtree model) generate the base learner in every iteration, for example, there are 10 features in the training data, and the *num_boost_round* is set to 100 which means the model will generate a optimal base learner in every iteration, so how does xgboost generate these 100 base learner using these 10 features?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in the details of the algorithm, you should take a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf . It is the original paper describing the xgboost algorithm.

Chapter 2 in this paper (TREE BOOSTING IN A NUTSHELL) might be enough if you want to get a high level overview.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been working on reading the source code on the GitHub, but it is too hard for me to understand all the aspect of the code. Thanks again!